# Entity not saving to database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have a edit action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CompositeModel cm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(cm.model_1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (cm.model_2List == null) return View(cm);
            foreach (var model in cm.model_2List)
            {
                var row = ( from s in db.model_2
                            where s.rid == model.rid
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();
                row = model;
                db.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { log(); }
    }
    return View(cm);
}
```

The first `db.SaveChangesa()` saves the changes to the database but the second one (in the loop) does not. The model_2 is built from a database table that has no ID column so that's why i look for the row via the `rid` column (it holds a unique guid, its not classified as an id column, i don't know how to assign a column the uniqueidentifier type, and maybe that would fix my problem).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I have done some more testing and it seems that the problem lies somewhere in the fact that this table doesn't posses a primary key column. I have a similar piece of code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CompositeModel2 cm2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(cm2.Model_3).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (cm2.Model_4List == null) return View(cm2);
            foreach (var model in cm2.Model_4List)
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { log(); }
     }
    return View(cm2);
}
```

that works as intended.

Comment: Are you sure that `cm.model_2` is not `null`? And other question, what exactly are you doing with your LINQ statement at the beginning of your loop, when you set the `row` to the `model` one line below?

Comment: The row above the if statement checks if it is in fact null, and if it is, it just returns the view. In the LINQ statement looks for the aforementioned row that needs changing, and then sets its values to the values of the submitted model. At least that's how i see it, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes we can see that you are checking that. The thing is that if cm.model_2 is in fact null, the second db.SaveChanges is never called in the loop.

Comment: My premise is that the object is not null when viewed in debugger, and thus the if statement resolves to `false`, and the loop starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I have managed to solve my problem by running a sql statement on the database:

```
ALTER table [db].[dbo].[table]
ADD id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
GO
```

and that solved the problems Entity was having with the table.